# Converting interval to time data type without losing precision?

Tags: postgresql, time

I have a time duration for example 65.463 seconds stored as a interval.

Unfortunately an external app doesn't understand the interval data type so I was trying to use the time datatype. The doc says that time has a resolution of microseconds. But when I cast interval to time I lose the milliseconds!

I'm using  duration::time  in a VIEW definition to perform the cast from interval to time.

Is there another way to do the cast/convert?

Edit: I should have said that i did try using explicit precision when casting to a time ie ::time(3) but didn't seem to make any difference.

Edit:  View definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.timetest
AS SELECT user_sessionlaps.laptime,
    user_sessionlaps.laptime::text AS test1,
    user_sessionlaps.laptime::text::interval AS test2,
    user_sessionlaps.laptime::text::interval::time without time zone AS test3,
    user_sessionlaps.laptime::text::interval::time(3) without time zone AS test4
   FROM user_sessionlaps;
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just return it as e.g. a decimal representing the number of seconds?

Comment: That was what i was originally doing but the 3rd party dashboarding app doesn't seem have the ability to take the decimal and render it as a formatted time ... it expects times to be in a TIME.  I tried sending it as a formatted string, but then it displays a string which it then can't do things like compare two times, or add them together.

Comment: The cast to `time` **does** preserve the milliseconds and microseconds: https://rextester.com/NPI65349

Comment: So why do i get something different .... i've updated the question with my view definition

Comment: Maybe your SQL client doesn't display that properly. Try formatting the time **on the server** (rather than through the SQL client) using `to_char()` as I did in my example.

Answer (score 1):

As @a_horse_with_no_name said in his comment, casting to `time` does preserve milliseconds, but some editors may choose to leave that out for the sake of readability. If I take an interval with milliseconds and cast it as `time`, it looks like the millisecond and microsecond values have been truncated, but if I call `to_char` on it, you can see that the precision has been maintained under the hood.

```
WITH ct AS (
  SELECT '3 MINUTES -3 SECONDS 3 MICROSECONDS'::interval as i
)
SELECT i,
    i::time without time zone,
    to_char(i::time without time zone, 'MI:SS.US')
FROM ct
```

[image: The interval as is, as time, and as time formatted with to_char]